# printing a string that must contain #{foo} with no substitution

Tags: ruby

I need to manipulate a string that must contain " #{foo} " , as is, without subtitution for foo.

Is that possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way:

```
puts %q{just text: #{foo}}
```

I use it for more complex strings

Answer (score 3):

Use single quotes:

```
puts '#{foo}'
```

Or escape the hash character:

```
puts "\#{foo}"
```